# Why does this dictionary in Python only store the last input?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
while (lines < travels + 1):
    data = lines + 1
    startFrom = raw_input ('The package travels from: ')
    startFrom = str(startFrom)
    arriveIn = raw_input ('The package arrives to: ')
    arriveIn = str(arriveIn)
    pack = raw_input('Number of packages: ')
    pack = int(pack)
    print startFrom, '--->', arriveTo, ': ', pack
    capacity = {}
    if capacity.has_key(startFrom):
        capacity[startFrom] = capacity[startFrom] + pack
    else:
        capacity[startFrom] = pack
print capacity
```

At the end it only prints (and only stores) the last input given and doesn't increment the value or add new data to the dictionary. I also tried with defaultdic but the result was the same.

Comment: `capacity = {}` is the culprit. Also don't use `has_key`, it is deprecated. Use `if startFrom in capacity`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You reset the `capacity` to a empty `dict` each iteration through the loop.

```
capacity = {} #Create it before the loop and use this through out the below loop.
while (lines < travels + 1):
 data = lines + 1
 startFrom = raw_input ('The package travels from: ')
 startFrom = str(startFrom)
 arriveIn = raw_input ('The package arrives to: ')
 arriveIn = str(arriveIn)
 pack = raw_input('Number of packages: ')
 pack = int(pack)
 print startFrom, '--->', arriveTo, ': ', pack
 if startFrom in capacity:#Style change and more pythonic
  capacity[startFrom] = capacity[startFrom] + pack
 else:
  capacity[startFrom] = pack
print capacity
```

That should fix it.